# Kubuntu 15.04 Doesnt save custom keyboard shortcuts

Tags: settings

Every time I try to assign a keyboard shortcut, it only stays functional until I log in again, then it resets to its original settings. Anyone have any ideas how to get it to keep my settings from session to session? Or was this feature removed for some reason? I recall it working fine in 12

Comment: are you fully updated?? apt-get dist-upgrade
If that does not fix the issue, the rights on the prefs file might not have been transferred properly if you imported a home directory from another computer or distro upgrade.

I would chown -R <user>:<group> my home directory, and try again.

Comment: Its a fresh install, I did try both ideas, and neither seemed to work

Comment: It might be an actually be a bug. As a workaround, you might want to save and restore your previous session at login, instead of starting up from scratch every time. You should find that in the system settings/control panel of your distro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not techinaly fixed, but a suitable work around for now.

So keyboard shortcuts made in the system settings -> keyboard shortcuts menu dont save, they go away when you relog, even with the session saved.

Work around for now, is to right click the k menu in the bottom corner, and edit applications. Select konsole and change its keyboard command.

This works for what I wanted, but would not work if someone wanted to actually have a keyboard shortcut run a complex command